# Installing iOS apps to multiple devices through network

Tags: ios, networking, ssh, push, updates

I have an app, which is not supposed to be on the AppStore, but I need to install it to several devices. After that, I need to deliver the updates the same way.

I know, that it is possible to do through some kind of network service, but I have no idea, how it should be developed. Can this be done over SSH or push, or anything else? Any ideas are higly appreciated!

**[UPD]**

To put it more accurately, I'm asking about a network service or the ways to develop one, which will AUTOMATICALLY install my new builds on the devices I need.

Comment: If fewer than the limit of 99 Ad-Hoc devices, you could do an Ad-Hoc distribution and updates through TestFlight.

Comment: @Thompsonian And what if I need to install the app, lets say, to 200 devices?

Comment: please see my answer. You need an ios developer enterprise license

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com) is a good AdHoc distribution if you don't want to distribute the .ipa file yourself. There is a 100 device limit on a standard ios developer license (the $99 one) but you can buy an [enterprise license](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) that is meant for this purpose and won't require UDID's (the standard one will) it can have unlimited devices. The price for it is $299.

If you want no user interactive for install check out 'App Blade' I personally haven't used it but I met the developers a few weeks back and they are really cool guys. Their software allows for MDM so you can automatically install updates. Check out their [feature site](https://appblade.com/features.html) The only thing is it costs money whereas TestFlight flight is free. (for now)

Comment: OK, thank you very much for the advice. But if I'd have an enterprise dev account, I will have to deliver my build to testers by hand. And what I want is an automatic delivery after app update.

Comment: TestFlight is great for this. You can upload a new build and if you use the TestFlight SDK you can have the users prompted to download the newest version. It will also let you send registered users (email) notifications of updates. Check out their SDK it can also alert you of crashes and feedback VERY simply.

Comment: The enterprise account will work with TestFlight if that's what you were concerned about.

Comment: Wow, that sounds great! Thank you! And one more question on TestFlight - does it support automatic installation of builds, or does it only prompt users about the updates?

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't allow for automatic installation but what you could do is check for the bundle version and cross check it with a server (there may even be a method in TestFlights SDK to check latest version number) and not allow the user to proceed to use the app until they have the most updated version.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I need( Still thank you for your precious help!

Comment: Check my answer again, I met a few guys that were working on your problem. Called App Blade. I haven't used it but it appears it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://testflightapp.com) web site. It allows you deploying app through email to test.

Answer (score 0):

After some time seaching the net I've finally found a framework that seems to be a perfect solution for my question:

http://hockeykit.net/